# In nodejs/express how to allow sitemap for crawler

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

In nodejs/express how to allow sitemap for crawler?

Below code is part of my application flow, where should I put my sitemap folder/files? and how to allow for crawler ? right now visit `domain/sitemap/sitemap.xml` shows not found..

project/app/app.js

app.js

```
require('./RouteHandler.js')(app, express);
```

RouteHandler.js

```
...
var routesIndex = require('./routes/Index/Base.js');
app.use('/', routesIndex);
...

module.exports = setupRoutes;
```

routes/Index/Base.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
   render .. view
});
module.exports = router;
```

Comment: use get method and render xml file or just use public directory

Comment: I use public directory now but I'm wondering how to render xml file??  `router.get('/sitemap.xml', function(req, res, next) {
   ??
});`

Comment: you can use "res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/sitemap.xml');" directly opens xml file

Comment: @OsmanErdi Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

we had a similar case, and we resolved it this way.

- write a separate js file that renders the xml files when needed and save it to a directory, cleaning your main web event loop from getting any longer.
- lets assume the folder name is sitemap, and the file is sitemap.xml, you can declare a static file in express this way

  app.use(express.static('sitemap'));
- OR, as I recommend to let a web server do it so the request doesn't even make it to your app, for me, I use nginx

  location /sitemap
          {
                  root /dir/to/app/dir/sitemap;
          }
  I hope this helps :)