# Serve static files with Express

Tags: node.js, express, mean-stack, sitemap

I'm trying to add a sitemap to a Express project with EJS set as it's engine.

The problem is my app does not allow a .html or .xml file to be in the path because of express.

I tried to set a public path but this crashed my app and seemed overly complicated:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

How would I go about simply adding a route to allow a .xml render?

Thanks!

Comment: check below link http://only4ututorials.blogspot.com/2017/05/how-to-serve-static-file-in-express-js.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ah figured it out with the help of:

[In nodejs/express how to allow sitemap for crawler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32427192/in-nodejs-express-how-to-allow-sitemap-for-crawler/32427672)

I created the sitemap.xml file in the public folder of my project then used this route:

```
router.get("/sitemap.xml", function(req, res, next){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/sitemap.xml'); 
});
```

Comment: Don't forget to select your answer!

Comment: This did the trick for me on a similar issue! Thank you so much!

Comment: Not working for me,google in webmaster tools says "downloading isnt successfull".